# Using REGEXMATCH with list input

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to see if a COL A contains anything from a specified list. (if it does, I put say a '1' in COL B, or '0' if not.

I'm currently doing it this slow, insane way. (putting this formula into col B - replace 'I20' with A20 for example).

Is there a better way?

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"SOUTHERN"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"GLASS"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"HOME"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"JOHN"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"ENTERPRISE"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"BRITISH A"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"WSELECTRICAL"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"VIKING"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"TASCHEN"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"FRANCY"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"MODELSHOP"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"APPLE"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"CURRYS"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"WATFORD"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"WICKES"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"LEYLAND"),1,0) + if(REGEXMATCH(I20,"IKEA"),1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'pipe' symbol `|` to look for multiple possible matches:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B1,"Words|To|Look|For")
```

[image]

Even better, have a list of words somewhere, `JOIN` them with pipes, and use that:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B1,JOIN("|",A$1:A$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. My only suggestion is to wrap `RegexMatch` in an `ArrayFormula`. Enter Something like this entered in cell B2 would look after the entire Column A: ``=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(A2:A, "SOUTHERN|GLASS|HOME|JOHN|ENTERPRISE|BRITISH|WSELECTRICAL|VIKING|TASCHEN|FRANCY|MODELSHOP|APPLE|CURRYS|WATFORD|WICKES|LEYLAND|IKEA")),""))``

Comment: Love the pipe symbol - didn't know we had it, that's awesome.

Not the biggest fan of array formulas but was thinking something along those lines might work too @Tedinoz

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem!